# ggplot shape not matching legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking to manually add a legend (I dont want to make the dataframe long in this case) but the legend shape doesnt match the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$time <- 1:nrow(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  
  #wt
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = wt, color = "wt name"), shape = 19, size = 4) +
  
  #drat
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = drat   , color = "drat name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = drat   , color = "drat name"), shape = 8, size = 4) +
  
  scale_colour_manual(name = "legend", values = c("wt name"     = "#F8766D",  
                                                    "drat name"   = "#B79F00"))
```

results in:

[image]

Other questions suggest using `scale_shape_manual` but I cant get it to work:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  
  #wt
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 4) +
  
  #drat
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = drat   , color = "drat name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = drat   , color = "drat name"), size = 4) +
  
  scale_colour_manual(name = "legend", values = c("wt name"     = "#F8766D",  
                                                    "drat name"   = "#B79F00")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("wt name" = 19,
                                "drat name" = 8 ))
```

gives this which ignores the shapes:

[image]

does anyone know what to change for this simple problem please? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to have a custom legend rather than reshaping your data (which would be the standard way to use ggplot), you need to map the shape as an aesthetic (i.e. put `shape =`  inside the `aes` call, and give it the name you wish to appear on the legend). You also need to ensure that both scales are given the same `name =`  if you want them to be merged in the legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$time <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wt, color = "wt name", shape = "wt name"), size = 4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = drat, color = "drat name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = drat, color = "drat name", shape ="drat name"), size = 4) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("wt name" = "#F8766D", "drat name" = "#B79F00"),
                      name = "legend") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("wt name" = 19, "drat name" = 8 ), 
                     name = "legend")
```

[image]

Or if you want them separated, give them different names:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$time <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wt, color = "wt name", shape = "wt name"), size = 4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = drat, color = "drat name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = drat, color = "drat name", shape ="drat name"), size = 4) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("wt name" = "#F8766D", "drat name" = "#B79F00"),
                      name = "legend2") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("wt name" = 19, "drat name" = 8 ), 
                     name = "legend1")
```

[image]

And, further to requests in the comments, if you want to have two legends but a single color and shape in each you will need to hack the `breaks` and `guide`, since this is not a standard use of aesthetic mapping.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

mtcars$time <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wt, color = "wt name", shape = "wt name"), size = 4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = drat, color = "drat name", size = "wt name")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = drat, color = "drat name", shape ="drat name"), size = 4) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("wt name" = 1.5), breaks = "wt name", 
                    name = "legend2") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("wt name" = "#F8766D", "drat name" = "#B79F00"),
                      name = "legend1", breaks = "drat name") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("wt name" = 19, "drat name" = 8 ), 
                     name = "legend2", breaks = "wt name") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 8, color = "#B79F00")),
         shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 19, color = "#F8766D")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. One follow question if you dont mind. If I wanted to break up the legend into two, I thought I break up the `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_shape_manual` into two separate calls but it didnt work something like so: `scale_colour_manual(values = c("wt name" = "#F8766D"),name = "legend2") +   scale_shape_manual(values = c("wt name" = 19 ), 
name = "legend2")`. Can two be added in this way or do you have to use `guide_legend`?

Comment: @user63230 just give them different names like "legend1" and "legend2". They should split automatically.

Comment: i tried that and I get an error `Scale for 'colour' is already present.`?

Comment: @user63230 that's weird. I'll add a complete reprex. Can you see if that works for you?

Comment: thanks but I wanted `legend1` to be a line color `#F8766D` with symbol `19`, `legend2` with line color `"#B79F00"` with symbol `8` if that makes sense? so two legends but only one in each. You have two legends with two in both, thanks

Comment: @user63230 so you want two legends describing different values for the same aesthetics? Would using version 1 but with greater spacing between the keys not give essentially the same effect? Do you want each legend to have a title as well as a key name even though there is only one element in each legend?

Comment: @user63230 what you're asking is possible but doesn't make a lot of sense in terms of how aesthetics are mapped to legends, so requires a bit of hacking of scales and guides. However, I think my update is what you are looking for.

Comment: excellent thats what I want except the line is missing in `legend2`?

Comment: @user63230 that's because you wanted a separate legend, and we had to use a custom `shape` legend to create it - this can't have a line in it. So to further complicate things, we now need to add another legend and merge it to get a line here. In this case, I have added a `size` scale and merged its legend with the shape legend to get the desired line.

Comment: Excellent answer, appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

possibly easier to melt your data to long first...
Also, no need to rename, you cean just set the legend's labels to your desire

```
library( data.table )
DT <- setDT(copy(mtcars), keep.rownames = TRUE)
#melt
plotdata <- melt(DT, id.vars = "time", measure.vars = c("wt","drat"))
#legend labels
legend_labels <- c("wt name", "drat name" )
ggplot( plotdata, aes( x = time, y = value, group = variable, shape = variable, colour = variable )) +
  geom_line( size = 1.5 ) +
  geom_point( size = 4 ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = "legend", labels = legend_labels, values = c("#F8766D", "#B79F00") ) + 
  scale_shape_manual( name = "legend", labels = legend_labels, values = c(19,8) )
```

[image]

Comment: added a vector for the legend's labels.. no renaming of columns needed this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here, two things have changed. I added `shape = ""` to each point layer. Then the guide layer helps merge the two legends

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  
  #wt
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = wt, color = "wt name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = wt, color = "wt name", shape = "wt name"), size = 4) +
  
  #drat
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = drat   , color = "drat name"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = time, y = drat   , color = "drat name", shape = "drat name"), size = 4) +
  
  scale_colour_manual(name = "legend", values = c("wt name"     = "#F8766D",  
                                                  "drat name"   = "#B79F00")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("wt name" = 19,
                                "drat name" = 8 )) +
  guides(shape = FALSE,
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(19, 8),
                                                   colour = c("#F8766D", "#B79F00"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of problems generaly has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from long to wide format. Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  select(wt, drat) %>%
  rename(c("wt name" = "wt", "drat name" = "drat")) %>%
  mutate(time = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("name"),
    names_to = "variable",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value, color = variable, shape = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "legend",
                      values = c("wt name" = "#F8766D", "drat name" = "#B79F00")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "legend",
                     values = c("wt name" = 19, "drat name" = 8 ))
```

[image]